# I'm able to produce my desired CSS float/clear behavior in Chrome, but NOT in IE11

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-float, internet-explorer-11

I'm attempting to position and group together a handful of input fields together. I've successfully positioned the elements how I'd like them to appear when the page is viewed in Chrome, but IE11 is not cooperating.

If you view the fiddle in Chrome, you should see my desired result where the Zip label and field are right next to the State label and field.
If you view the fiddle in IE11, you should see that the Zip label and field are off to the right of the City field.

Am I misusing the CSS properties and it's just showing up in Chrome the way I want it to by chance, or am I not correctly styling it for IE11?

I've moved the example into a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/66tcq78k/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="group-one">
    <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="all-fields" autocomplete="off">
    <label id="title-label" for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" class="all-fields" autocomplete="off">
    <label id="company-label" for="company">Company:</label>
    <input type="text" id="company" class="all-fields" autocomplete="off">
    <label id="street-label" for="street">Street Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="street" class="all-fields" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div id="group-two">
    <label id="city-label" class="right-label" for="city">City:</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" class="all-fields" autocomplete="off">
    <label id="state-label" class="right-label" for="state">State:</label>
    <input type="text" id="state" class="all-fields" maxlength="2" autocomplete="off">
    <label id="zip-label" for="zip">Zip:</label>
    <input type="text" id="zip" class="all-fields" autocomplete="off">
    <label id="phone-label" class="right-label" for="phone">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" class="all-fields" autocomplete="off">
    <label id="email-label" class="right-label" for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" class="all-fields" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
  width: 117px;
  clear: left;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15.5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px -1px #000;

}

input, label {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

input {
  padding-right: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 18px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  outline: none;
}

input:focus {
  border: 2px solid #75aaff;
  transition: 1s;
}

#group-one, #group-two {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: rgba(77,77,77,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(77,77,77,1) 0%, rgba(130,130,130,1) 50%, rgba(101,101,101,1) 77%, rgba(77,77,77,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(77,77,77,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(130,130,130,1)), color-stop(77%, rgba(101,101,101,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(77,77,77,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(77,77,77,1) 0%, rgba(130,130,130,1) 50%, rgba(101,101,101,1) 77%, rgba(77,77,77,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(77,77,77,1) 0%, rgba(130,130,130,1) 50%, rgba(101,101,101,1) 77%, rgba(77,77,77,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(77,77,77,1) 0%, rgba(130,130,130,1) 50%, rgba(101,101,101,1) 77%, rgba(77,77,77,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(77,77,77,1) 0%, rgba(130,130,130,1) 50%, rgba(101,101,101,1) 77%, rgba(77,77,77,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4d4d4d', endColorstr='#4d4d4d', GradientType=1 );
}

#state {
  width: 30px;
}

#zip {
  width: 72px;
  clear: none;
  float: none;
}

#zip-label {
  float: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 28px;
}

.right-label {
  width: 60px;
}

.labelfocus {
  color: #75aaff;
  transition: 1s;
}

#name-label {
  width: 49px;
  margin-left: 68px;
}

#title-label {
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: 82px;
}

#company-label {
  width: 76px;
  margin-left: 41px;
}

#city-label {
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

#state-label {
  width: 44px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

#phone-label {
  width: 52px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

#email-label {
  width: 47px;
  margin-left: 13px;
}
```

Comment: width: 255px for #group-two fixed the issue for me

Comment: That did it. Thank you.